# Is there any way that we can find from which class an segment fault is thrown?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, elf

The segment fault is due to an read access to `std::mutex::lock`, with `si_addr = 0x278`, and `si_code = SEGV_MAPERR`.

There are too many inline functions in the program, the stack only provides limited information that is not enough. The segment fault is raised from a certain deployment, and we have no clue how to reproduce that.

IMO, the `0x278` offset is too small, so it must be an offset in a certain class. For example, it should be like the following case

```
struct Dummy
{
    char c[0x278];
    std::mutex mtx;
};

std::lock_guard lock (reinterpret_cast<Dummy*>(nullptr)->mtx);
```

However, after check some candidate class, we find no `std::mutex` has offset with `0x278`.

So I wonder if there are some magic that we can scan all classes inside a certain namespace, and find all classes that have std::mutex defined at offset 0x278?

**EDIT**

Below is the stack I've seen. I removed some extra message like location to make it more readable.

```
faultSignalHandler(int, siginfo_t*, void*)
<unknown symbol>
___pthread_mutex_lock
std::__1::mutex::lock()
tDB::LearnerReadWorker::waitUntilDataAvailable(std::__1::unordered_map<unsigned long, DB::RegionLearnerReadSnapshot, std::__1::hash<unsigned long>, std::__1::equal_to<unsigned long>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<unsigned long const, DB::RegionLearnerReadSnapshot> > > const&, unsigned long, unsigned long)
```

Comment: Doesn't your debugger show you the stack?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat There is too many inline functions, so the stack is not so useful. The panic is not always reproducible.

Comment: What do inline functions have to do with the stack being useful? You need to repro just once to look at it. Did you already try the address sanitizer?

Comment: > What do inline functions have to do with the stack being useful? This is because the top frame won't access `std:mutex` itself, so the `std::mutex::lock` call is from some callee of the top frame. However, we have no clue where `std::mutex::lock` is actually called. I think this maybe due to the  callee function is inlined.

Comment: If you are lucky and the class happens to have vtable ptr, you can try to search the address near `std::mutex::lock` and find the vtable ptr, usually the typeinfo of the class is in the vtable entries

Comment: Hmm. What compiler are you using? How do you know `mutex::lock()` is the offender if it's not in the stack? How do you look at the stack if you can't repro locally, is this a dump?

Comment: *it must be an offset in a certain class.* It can be a class object in a class object.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ok, I can show you part of the stack

Comment: @273K Do you mean the offset may be from the outer class of the outer class of std::mutex, like `struct A { struct B { std::mutex mut; }; };`?

Comment: @konchy The deployment is not accessible to us, and the coredump is disabled. So barely we can't check the memory layout of the program when it panics if we can't find a way to reproduce

Comment: I mean `struct A { ...; std::mutex mut; }; struct B { ...; A a; };`

Comment: What about the rest of my questions?

Comment: `0x278` doesn't have to be an offset. It could be something uninitialized, or overwritten, or some random thing that was read because of other bugs in the program. It's not even certain that the call stack is correct, if something happened to clobber it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat We have a dedicated thread which will accept all kinds of signals, print enough information before we exit the program.

Comment: I see. I'd start with ASAN locally, or other automatic tools. Failing that, maybe [`pahole`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pahole) will be of use. You could also try parsing your source with libclang to look for `std::mutex` members, but that's probably way more complicated.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Actually I bisect my commits and locate a suspecious nullptr call, however, its offset is far smaller than 0x278

Comment: Perhaps one class is a member of the other, and the combined offest ends up as 0x278. Perhaps array indexing is involved somwhere.

Comment: segfault is a system error - normally generated by HW and trapped by OS. It means something is terribly wrong with program logic; there's a UB in your code - not essentially related to mutex usage. An uncaught buffer overrun could be the cause, as well as a null pointer dereference. You need a sanitizer test to find some potential failure points.

Answer (score 0):

> However, after check some candidate class, we find no std::mutex has offset with 0x278

You are correct in that there is likely some `NULL` pointer dereference resulting in access to address `0x278`.

However, that *doesn't mean* that there should be an `std::mutex` with such offset in one of your classes.

For example, on Linux / x86_64 when using GLIBC, the disassembly looks like this (on my system):

```
Dump of assembler code for function ___pthread_mutex_lock:
   0x0008b570 <+0>:     mov    0x10(%edi),%eax
...
```

This function would crash at address `0x10` if it were passed a `NULL` `pthread_mutex_t`.

It looks like `pthread_mutex_t` *is* the very first data member of `std::mutex` using Clang / libc++, so possibly you should be looking for a class that has `std::mutex` at offset `0x268` (if your `pthread_mutex_lock` matches mine; if it doesn't you'll need to adjust the offset accordingly).

P.S. Suppose that you find a class `C` that has `std::mutex` at the desired offset. You are *no closer* to figuring out the bug with that knowledge, so the exercise is kind of pointless.